# Deploying ember-cli app to Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, ember.js, ember-cli

What do I put in my Procfile to deploy an ember-cli generated app to Heroku?

```
=== web (1X): `ember server`
web.1: crashed 2014/04/10 13:19:57 (~ 48s ago)  

=== web (1X): `npm start`
web.1: crashed 2014/04/10 13:22:11 (~ 2m ago)
```

Comment: Unless I misunderstand your question, the fact that it is an ember-cli app should make no difference, right?  It is just a normal Ember app?  Are you deploying it with a server app as well?

Comment: It's probably not the best, but you might want to try

`web: ember server --port $port`

That should do it?

Comment: https://github.com/tonycoco/heroku-buildpack-ember-cli

Answer (score 5):

You could use the Heroku Ember CLI buildpack: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-emberjs

Answer (score 4):

I have this in my Procfile and it's is working for me:

```
web: ember serve --environment production --port $PORT
```

I followed the instructions from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/tonycoco/ef16b4972494db5ad2a6), which is where I got that Procfile.

The ember-cli version and dependencies in the gist are out of date, which was causing my app to crash similar to yours.

I needed to add/replace the packages listed in the "dependencies" section of my package.json file with the packages ember-cli puts into the "devDependencies" section of package json.  When I was done my package.json file looked like this:

```
{
  "name": "your-apps-name",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "directories": {
    "doc": "doc",
    "test": "test"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ember server",
    "build": "ember build",
    "test": "ember test",
    "postinstall": "bower install"
  },
  "repository": "https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.10.0"
  },
  "author": "Your Name",
  "license": "Your App's License",
  "devDependencies": {
    "ember-cli": "0.0.28",
    "originate": "0.1.5",
    "broccoli-ember-hbs-template-compiler": "^1.5.0",
    "loom-generators-ember-appkit": "^1.1.1",
    "express": "^4.1.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.2.0",
    "glob": "^3.2.9"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bower": "^1.3.3",
    "broccoli-template": "0.1.1",
    "ember-cli": "0.0.28",
    "originate": "0.1.5",
    "broccoli-ember-hbs-template-compiler": "^1.5.0",
    "loom-generators-ember-appkit": "^1.1.1",
    "express": "^4.1.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.2.0",
    "glob": "^3.2.9"
  }
}
```

Comment: The core team has said to not run in production mode like this for a server. A better solution is: https://github.com/tonycoco/heroku-buildpack-ember-cli

Answer (score 2):

Procfile:

```
web: npm run start
```

Package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "ember serve --port=${PORT}",
  "build": "ember build",
  "test": "ember test",
  "postinstall": "bower install"
},
```

and rename devDependencies block and add `bower` as a depency:

```
"devDependencies": { ... }

to 

"dependencies": { 
  "bower": "1.3.12"
  ...
}
```

but add devDependencies again and add ember-cli there for ember to detect your app:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "ember-cli": "0.1.15"
}
```

A bit more information and further links can be found from my blogpost:

https://personalwebdevelopment.wordpress.com/2015/02/23/deploying-ember-cli-app-to-heroku/

Answer (score 0):

you can try with 'npm start' or 'ember server'

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Ember buildpack recommended by Heroku: https://www.heroku.com/emberjs

To define this buildpack for an existing application, you'll need to run the command below:

```
heroku buildpacks:set https://codon-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/emberjs.tgz
```